# How to recursively query with sparql?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have RDF like this:

```
<companyA> <heldBy> "companyB" .
<companyA> <heldBy> "companyC" .
<companyB> <heldBy> "companyD" .
```

It's a stockholder relation, what I wanna do is to query all holders of `companyA` and mark them by level.

For example, `companyB` is level 1, `companyD` is level 2.

How can I do this with `sparql`? Or is it doable with `sparql`?

Thanks for the help!

---

According to the comment section, I think this might be doable with querying all holders with `select ?holder where { <companyA> <heldBy>+ ?holder }`.

Then calculate the length of the path to these nodes, sort them into levels.

Might even do this with SPARQL only, working on it.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate length of path between nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198889/calculate-length-of-path-between-nodes)

Comment: Recursive query is easy, just use a one-or-more property path expression: `{ <companyA> <heldBy>+ ?holder }`. To get the levels is more tricky though. See the related question (linked above) for a  solution to that.

Comment: I notice that the predicates above are all literals. If that's accurate, you're going to run into trouble. You'll want those to be URIs instead.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra That answer is very helpful, I think I can use `{ <companyA> <heldBy>+ ?holder }` to get all nodes first then calculate their length of path later. Thank you sir.